# Is there a way I can improve my own developed function to obtain histograms compared to when using readily available functions?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, histogram

I am required to develop my own function to obtain the histogram of an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXuvK.png) and then I need to compare the histogram obtained when using built-in functions.

The following is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_Ga = cv2.imread('Images/Ga.png',0) # converting the image attached to grayscale

#To display image before equalization
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
plt.imshow(img_Ga, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title("Original Ga.png")

a = np.zeros((256,),dtype=np.float16)
b = np.zeros((256,),dtype=np.float16)

height,width=img_Ga.shape

#finding histogram
for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
        g = img_Ga[j,i]
        a[g] = a[g]+1

print(a)# contains the histogram

plt.plot(a)
plt.title('Histogram of Ga.png')
plt.xlabel('Pixel Intensity')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.grid(True)
```

When plotting `a` I obtain the following [histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBV1k.png).

Then when I plot using `cv2.calcHist` through the following lines of code:

```
hist_Ga = cv2.calcHist(images=[img_Ga],channels=[0],mask=None,histSize=[256],ranges=[0,255])
plt.plot(hist_Ga)
plt.title('Histogram of the Ga.png')
plt.xlabel('Pixel Intensity')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.grid(True)
```

I obtain the following [histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWPAj.png).

They are somewhat similar but not the same is there a way I can improve my result?

The same goes when trying to obtain the equalised histogram:

```
#performing histogram equalization
tmp = 1.0/(height*width)
b = np.zeros((256,),dtype=np.float16)

for i in range(256):
    for j in range(i+1):
        b[i] += a[j] * tmp;
    b[i] = round(b[i] * 255);

# b now contains the equalized histogram
b=b.astype(np.uint8)

print(b)

plt.plot(b)
plt.title('Histogram Equalisation of Ga.png')
plt.xlabel('Pixel Intensity')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.grid(True)
```

Plot `b` got me the following [histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QswC.png).

Then when obtaining the equalised histogram through built-in functions:

```
img_Ga_eq = cv2.equalizeHist(img_Ga)
# Calculate and plot the equalised histogram of the image in grayscale
hist_Ga_gray = cv2.calcHist(images = [img_Ga_eq], channels = [0], mask = None, histSize = [256], ranges = [0,255])
plt.plot(hist_Ga_gray)
```

I got this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwDkT.png).

My approach to obtain the equalised histogram here does not seem to be working at all, is there maybe a different approach I can consider?

Comment: your first code looks correct, so if that differs from opencv/numpy/scipy, they probably do something strange. and don't bother with float16, that'll do calculations entirely in software because no CPU supports it. use float32/float64. those are the normal ones.

Comment: first code looks correct, but the plot doesn't, probably because you mess around with float16, and matplotlib doesn't support that -- calcHist needs the upper bound to be 256 -- histograms can be considered "probability density functions". next, calculate a cumulative distribution function (CDF) from the PDF. when you have that, you can think about equalization, which involves inverting the CDF.

Comment: Thank you I have a habit of using float16 changed them to float64 and they match. Could you further elaborate on the equalised histrogram method? I tried to use np.cumsum and I got the same plot but a cleaner curve then I tried to invert it as you said and I got an empty plot.

Comment: inversion meaning you have f(x) = y and you need f^-1(y) = x, so for the CDF that requires a lot of lookups on the data. you'd look up the index (x) where the function is (y=) 0, 1, 2, ... 255.